# How to change session variable 0 and 1 on each page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, session, ads

I have a code which I want to run with a wordpress site, this is working fine on simple and regular websites which is not cached but following php code is not working in cached website, which wp-rocket plugin or auto optimized plugin is installed, unfortunately I can't remove those plugin, please help me also I can't use javascript...

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
session_start();
    }
   ?>


<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
 if($_SESSION['test'] == 0)
 {
  $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
    ?>
 <!----place your Second ads here--->




    <!----Second ads end here-->
 <?php
 }
    else
 {
  $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
  ?>
 <!----place your First ads here--->




    <!----First ads end here-->
  <?php
 }
}
else
{
 ?>
<!----place your first ads here  this is default ads-->

 <!----First ads end here-->
<?php
$_SESSION['test'] = 0;
}
?>
```

As you can see that I want to swap ads on every refresh of page.

Comment: `session_start();` should be always on top but `sessions` are stored server-side so it has nothing to do with cache i think.

Comment: You'd have to make an exception within your caching system. Seeing as the caching engines just completely cache the served HTML, the ads will be saved into those files. What caching-plugin are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying ..I am using wp-rocket or auto optimized plugin in my wordpress site.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you solve it? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
    <?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
<?php 
    if(empty($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start();
    }
?>
instead of
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start();
    }
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
//set a variable to prevent 2 if statements from executing
$x='0';
//for the first time the page is loaded
    if(!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
        $_SESSION['test'] = '0'
        }

    if(($_SESSION['test'] == '1' && $x=='0'){
        //place second ads here
        $_SESSION['test'] = '0';
        $x='1';
        }
    if(($_SESSION['test'] == '0') && $x=='0'){
        //place first ads here
        $_SESSION['test'] = '1';
        $x='1';
        }
?>
```

and add this in your header

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```